# Asp.net fileupload transfer rate

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, file-transfer

Is there any way to easly know Transferrate between server/client during un filupload upload? Because uploading a file of 4,13Mb take about 5 or 6 minutes.... Is there anyway we can track it, by writing it in flatfile, email, response.write anything!! We're stuck.

Thanks to help us :(!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you're using the built-in asp:FileUpload control.  Some third party AJAX-based upload controls probably do this, but I don't know of any offhand.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.

HTTP works this way: you send ALL data and, after that, server begins to process your request.

But you can write some client code (flash, applet, silverlight) which break a file in pieces and send them, one at time, to server. This way you can compute your transfer rate.

Comment: Well thanks. I'm goin to download a file which i know the weight, and divide it by the timespan. :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a flash upload tool like [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), by which you can detect the upload speed, and then send the total time/speed to the server once the file is done.